# Only Farm Administrators can see Social Notes on a news page

Tags: social-note

I know this has been asked before, but I haven't found any satisfactory answers.  I have a publishing site that has had the Social Comments user control added but users can only see their own comments and not those posted by others.

()

The only account that can see all comments is the Farm Account.  Even me, as a Site Collection Administrator cannot see all comments.

I think this is coming down to permissions somewhere, but I cannot figure out where.  The news page shows up in search, so it has been indexed (It seems to be the security trimming that isn't / hasn't happened).  Only incremental crawls have run over the content so far, no Full Crawls have run.  I can't just kick off a Full Crawl as it's a large system and Full Crawls run once a month.

The "User Profile Service - Activity Feed Job" and "User Profile Service - Activity Feed Cleanup Job" timer jobs are both running frequently.

"Newsfeeds" are enabled in the MySite Settings and the Security Trimming Options are set to "Check all links for permission".  I am sure that I can change these settings to Show all links regardless of permission and get it to work, but since this is a large enterprise production system I don't want to (and can't) just flip this switch as that wouldn't be fixing the root permission / search trimming issues.

I need to fix this ASAP, so any advice would be greatly apprciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you find any solution for this issues. Please updates ASAP even I have the same issue